# I am updating this in view file by clicking it and want to show in view file without refreshing it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, database, cakephp-3.0

```
$scope.pause = function(userid){

    var id = $scope.userid;
    var status = 3;

    getClients.status(id,status).then(function(response)
    {
        console.log('Response',response);
        $scope.clients = response.data;   
        console.log('Data',$scope.clients);

        $scope.cancel();
    }); 

};
```

I am updating this  in view file by clicking it and want to show in view file without refreshing it.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, it's hard to understand?

Comment: want to do auto reload after i edit an page ..the values are inserting in db..but not getting reload..i hv yo refresh the page

Comment: So what you can do is after inserting data in db, you should explicitly call function which gets data from database which you must be calling on page load.So you will always  get updated data and don't forget to bind it in $scope variable.

Comment: i am using options like deactivate pause etc..n assigned roles to it..i dont want to refresh the page.and can u shw me an example for dat?

Answer (score 0):

Solution,

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="controllerName" ng-int="getData()">

</div>
```

JS

```
    app.controller("name",fucntion(){

    $scope.getData = function(){
      //api call to get data from database
       $scope.data = resultData;
    }


    $scope.yourEditFunction = function(){
    //make API call to update data in database 
    $scope.getData();
   }

    })
```

But ideally if you assign your get API result to an `$scope` variable and later in edit function update it then there is no need to refresh page angular will update the data for you.